# Titled Border on JList in Nimbus UI issues

Tags: java, jlist, nimbus, titled-border

I just want the background of the JList white, from border-to-border. However, the picture below shows exactly my issue. There is a TitledBorder around each of these JLists. The second one is as-is and the white extends into the border. The first one I have set opaque to false, and set background to white, but only the inside, minus the insets is white. I'm hoping I don't have to create a ListCellRenderer or override a paint method to accomplish such a simple task. Any suggestions?

[image: Custom Program]

```
     class TextTab extends JPanel
     {
        String[] textOptions = new String[]{"1 line of text","2 lines of text","3 lines of text","Chest Name","Script with Tail (1 Color)","Script with Tail (2 Color)"};
        String[] numberOptions = new String[]{"1\"","2\"","3\"","4\"","6\"","8\"","10\""};
        JList<String> textList = new JList<String>(textOptions);
        JList<String> numberList = new JList<String>(numberOptions);
        GridBagLayout ttGlay = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel textNumOptions = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane textNumOptionsPane = new JScrollPane(textNumOptions);

        public TextTab()
        {
           textList.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Standard Text"));
           textList.setOpaque(false);
           textList.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           numberList.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Pre-Cut Numbers"));

           setLayout(ttGlay);
           gbc.weightx = 1;
           gbc.weighty = 1;

           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy = 0;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTH;
           gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
           gbc.gridwidth = 1;
           gbc.gridheight = 1;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
           add(textList,gbc);

           gbc.gridx = 1;
           gbc.gridy = 0;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTH;
           gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
           gbc.gridwidth = 1;
           gbc.gridheight = 1;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,10);
           add(numberList,gbc);

           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy = 1;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTH;
           gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
           gbc.gridwidth = 2;
           gbc.gridheight = 1;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,10,10);
           add(textNumOptionsPane,gbc);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, what *exactly* are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want the inside white, border-to-border. Currently, the two different JLists either the white extends out into the border, or the white too small inside the borders.

Comment: The `TitleBorder` is transparent...

Comment: Is that supposed to be helpful? Because I'm not following how that can solve my issue

Comment: Just so we're clear, I hate Nimbus :P - The `TitleBorder` is transparent, therefore it's just showing the background color the component below it. From what I can derive, you want the content of the `JScrollPane` (the area within the curved borders) to be white and the "title" be the same color as the panel

Comment: The scrollpane is that empty thing at the bottom. You're just looking at two JLists there at the top.

And btw, Nimbus was the only UI I found to render the components the way I wanted. I have noticed since the start of this project that there are a few issues with it, so I won't argue that it's not an ideal UI.

Comment: Oh dear lord, it's the `TitledBorder` :P - Okay, this may not be fixable.  As I said, the `TitledBorder` is transparent, it has no color/fill of it's own.  Any solution will be hack, especially because you'd be trying to rely on the border effect generated by Nimbus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the paint method and creating my own ListCellRenderer like I originally thought to do. It was a little time consuming, but it solved my issue.

[image: a picture of my program]

```
     class TextTab extends JPanel
     {
        String[] textOptions = new String[]{"1 line of text","2 lines of text","3 lines of text","Chest Name","Script with Tail (1 Color)","Script with Tail (2 Color)"};
        String[] numberOptions = new String[]{"1\"","2\"","3\"","4\"","6\"","8\"","10\""};
        CustomJList<String> textList = new CustomJList<String>(textOptions);
        CustomJList<String> numberList = new CustomJList<String>(numberOptions);
        GridBagLayout ttGlay = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        NimbusCellRenderer cr = new NimbusCellRenderer();
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JScrollPane textNumOptionsPane = new JScrollPane(pnl);

        public TextTab()
        {
           ttGlay.rowHeights = new int[]{0,137};  

           textList.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(SoftBevelBorder.LOWERED),"Standard Text"));
           numberList.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(SoftBevelBorder.LOWERED),"Pre-Cut Numbers"));
           textList.setOpaque(false);
           textList.setCellRenderer(cr);
           numberList.setOpaque(false);
           numberList.setCellRenderer(cr);
           textList.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           numberList.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           textList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
           numberList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

           setLayout(ttGlay);
           gbc.weightx = 1;
           gbc.weighty = 1;

           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy = 0;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTH;
           gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
           gbc.gridwidth = 1;
           gbc.gridheight = 1;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
           add(textList,gbc);

           gbc.gridx = 1;
           gbc.gridy = 0;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTH;
           gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
           gbc.gridwidth = 1;
           gbc.gridheight = 1;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,10);
           add(numberList,gbc);

           gbc.gridx = 0;
           gbc.gridy = 1;
           gbc.anchor = gbc.NORTH;
           gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
           gbc.gridwidth = 2;
           gbc.gridheight = 1;
           gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,10,10);
           add(textNumOptionsPane,gbc);
        }

        class CustomJList<E> extends JList<E>
        {
           public CustomJList(){super();}
           public CustomJList(E[] listData){super(listData);}
           public CustomJList(ListModel<E> dataModel){super(dataModel);}
           public CustomJList(Vector<? extends E> listData){super(listData);}

           @Override
           public void paint(Graphics g)
           {
              Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
              g2.setColor(getBackground());
              if(!isOpaque())g2.fillRect(getInsets().left-4,getInsets().top-4,getWidth()-getInsets().left-getInsets().right+8,getHeight()-getInsets().top-getInsets().bottom+8);
              super.paint(g);
           }
        }

        class NimbusCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object>
        {
           public NimbusCellRenderer()
           {
              setOpaque(true);
           }

           public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus)
           {
              setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,5,0,0));
              setText(value.toString());
              Color background;
              Color foreground;

              if (isSelected&&list.hasFocus())
              {
                 background = new Color(57,105,138);
                 foreground = Color.WHITE;
              }
              else
              {
                 background = Color.WHITE;
                 foreground = Color.BLACK;
              }

              if(list.hasFocus()&&isSelected)
              {
                 setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(115,164,209),1),new LineBorder(new Color(72,120,155),1)),new EmptyBorder(0,3,0,0)));
              }

              setBackground(background);
              setForeground(foreground);
              return this;
           }
        }
     }
```